# "Process exited with code 0" when E2E tests failed at jasmine-spec-reporter

Tags: jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing, jasmine-spec-reporter

My configuration:

- Windows 10
- npm 5.3.0
- node v8.4.0
- jasmine 2.8.0
- jasmine-spec-reporter 4.2.1
- protractor 5.1.2

Previously I have used standard jasmine logger for E2E tests output.
Recently I installed jasmine-spec-reporter and output looks better.
But now I have problem in TeamCity.
After test execution in TeamCity I alway have "Process exited with code 0", even if some tests FAILED.
With standard logger I didn't faced such problem.
Could you please suggest how to solve this issue.

TeamCity output:

```
I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
Jasmine started

  1 LoginComponent
    x should set focus to the Password field after incorrect password has been entered
      - Expected false to be truthy.
          at Function.CustomMatchers.expectToBeFocused (D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent\work\e2eng2\ng2\e2e\matchers\custom-matchers.ts:13:6)
          at UserContext.<anonymous> (D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent\work\e2eng2\ng2\e2e\tests\login.e2e.ts:53:18)
          at new ManagedPromise (D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent\work\e2eng2\ng2\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1067:7)
          at ControlFlow.promise (D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent\work\e2eng2\ng2\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2396:12)
          at TaskQueue.execute_ (D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent\work\e2eng2\ng2\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2970:14)
          at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent\work\e2eng2\ng2\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2953:27)
          at asyncRun (D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent\work\e2eng2\ng2\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2860:25)

**************************************************
*                    Failures                    *
**************************************************

1) LoginComponent should set focus to the Password field after incorrect password has been entered
  - Expected false to be truthy.

Executed 1 of 9 specs (1 FAILED) (8 SKIPPED) in 10 secs.
I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
Process exited with code 0
```

My protractor.conf.js

```
require('ts-node').register({
  compilerOptions: {
    noEmitHelpers: false
  }
});
var helpers = require('./helpers');
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;

exports.config = {
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/ng2/',

  // use `npm run e2e`
  specs: [
    helpers.root('e2e/**/*.e2e.ts')
  ],
  exclude: [],

  framework: 'jasmine2',

  allScriptsTimeout: 110000,

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 600000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  directConnect: true,

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        '--start-maximized'
      ]
    }
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    jasmine.getEnv().clearReporters();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({  
      displayStacktrace: 'all',
      suite: {
        displayNumber: true,
      },
      spec: {
        displayPending: true,
        displayStacktrace: true,
      },
      summary: {
        displayDuration: true,
      },
      prefixes: {
        successful: '+ ',
        failed: 'x ',
        },
    }));
  },

   useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.
My problem was that I kill all other reporters.
To fix it it is enough to delete this row

```
jasmine.getEnv().clearReporters();
```